# How to enable localization for Custom Action on Ribbon?

Tags: ribbon, localization

I need to make my custom solution for SharePoint 2010 multilingual, I have a Elements.xml file where all my ribbons controls are described but how can in reference to .resx from there and how can i be sure that correct language and culture will be choosed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Sharepoint element.xml modules are localized the same way.

First of all, you need to deploy your resx files into SharePoint Resources mapped folder.

[image: Resources mapped folder]

After this, you can use following syntax to reference your localized resources:

$Resources: *ResourceFileNameWithoutExtension*, *ResourceName*

Code sample:

```
<CustomAction
  Id="MyTestCustomAction"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.Read">
          <Tab
            Id="Ribbon.Read"
            Title="$Resources:TestResources,MyBrowseTabTitle;"
            Sequence="100"
            Command="ReadTab"
            Description=""
            CssClass="ms-browseTab"
            >
            <Scaling Id="Ribbon.Read.Scaling" />
            <Groups Id="Ribbon.Read.Groups" />
          </Tab>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

Comment: I'm unable to get this working in 2013, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746563/sharepoint-2013-custom-ribbon-localization-not-working

Answer (score 0):

We use a resource helper that wraps `SPUtility.GetLocalizedString` in code and which can be called with a resource file name, an LCID and of course the resource key. For display purposes yoiu would call this with the current thread's UICulture LCID.

ASPX /ASCX files work differently, they reference resx files stored in the Web apps IIS folder (App_GlobalResources). These can be deployed to the SharePoint root (14-hive) in the config\resources folder. These get deployed to the IIS folder using `%STSADM% -o copyappbincontent`

Elements.xml can just reference the resources directly i.e. :

Name="$Resources:RESOURCEFILENAME,RESOURCEKEY;"

So, 3 options:

1. From Code: `SPUtility.GetLocalizedString`
2. Regular resource (i.e. elements.xml): Name="$Resources:RESOURCEFILENAME,RESOURCEKEY;"
3. ASPX / ASCX : `App_GlobalResources` and `%STSADM% -o copyappbincontent`